# Php : read output from exec

Tags: php, python

I'm launching a Python script from PHP and I'd like to get the line printed from that Python:

```
exec( "python plotModule.py $myArray[0] $myArray[1]",  $output, $ret_code);
$fp = fopen('logDisp.txt', 'w');
fwrite($fp, "$output");
fclose($fp);
```

In Python I have a `print("hello")` in order to test if it's working. Nothing is written in logDisp.txt file.

Can you tell me why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You try write $output as string, but it`s an array

Use foreach or $output[0]

Answer (score 0):

```
exec( "python plotModule.py $myArray[0] $myArray[1]",  $output, $ret_code);
$fp = fopen('logDisp.txt', 'w');
fwrite($fp, json_encode($output));
fclose($fp);
```

Here you can see the jsonified response